# Single Google API for finding multiple addresses lat long

Tags: android, google-api

Is there a Google API which will provide the lat-long of multiple addresses? I have to find the lat-long of multiple addresses and store them in my database. I would like to implement a `for` or `foreach` loop for that.

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality. But how many are we talking? Once stored in database, you don't need to do the lookup again?

Comment: But in my app there are lot of api to call and many of them have address to fetch lat long and it takes lot of net consumption for that and also the address may change so i need to find out lat long again for that, so i need to implement in single api so that net is not so consumed

Comment: Perhaps you can use OpenStreetMap, to store a section of the map within your app. This way making the geocoding happen locally.